# Create a textbox inside a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a input control inside a table row on every append. Basically like a shopping cart where I can add a quantity for every item in the table. I am struggling. I get [object HTMLInputElement] displayed when I do it as per below.

```
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
var create = document.body.appendChild(x);

let carttable = document.getElementById('cartlist');
let item = items[index];
let row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `
    <td(${items.indexOf(item)})">${item.title}</td>
   <td>${item.genre}</td>
   <td>${"R" + item.price }</td>
   <td>${x}</td> `;
carttable.append(row);
```

Comment: because you are building a string and contacting a string and an object. Either you have to build the input as a string or build your table row as DOM objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the `append` method to add your created `input` to a `td` and add that `td` to the `row` element.

```
let carttable = document.getElementById('cartlist');
let item = items[index];
let row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `
  <td(${items.indexOf(item)})">${item.title}</td>
  <td>${item.genre}</td>
  <td>${"R" + item.price }</td>
`;

let cell = document.createElement('td');
let input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("type", "text");
input.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
cell.append(input);
row.append(cell);

carttable.append(row);
```

Or instead of creating your input with `document.createElement` add it to your Template literal string in the `row.innerHTML`.

```
let carttable = document.getElementById('cartlist');
let item = items[index];
let row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `
  <td(${items.indexOf(item)})">${item.title}</td>
  <td>${item.genre}</td>
  <td>${"R" + item.price }</td>
  <td><input type="text" value="Hello World!"></td>
`;

carttable.append(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string directly for this purpose instead of `document.createElement("input")`:

```
let carttable = document.getElementById('cartlist');
let item = items[index];
let row = document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = `
   <td (${items.indexOf(item)})">${item.title}</td>
   <td>${item.genre}</td>
   <td>${"R" + item.price }</td>
   <td><input type="text" value="Hello World!" /></td>`;
carttable.append(row);
```